# QwtPlot not inhereting stylesheet in QtCreator

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qwt, qtstylesheets

I'm using a QwtPlot to draw some data in a fairly heavily styled application. I'm using QtCreator as an IDE, and load one stylesheet for the whole program at the start to keep a consistent look and feel across the whole thing using

```
qApp->setStyleSheet(style);
```

All the built in controls obey the style I set here, except for my QwtPlot. Currently all I'm doing in the style sheet is trying to set the foreground colour to white with

```
QwtPlot
{
    color: white;
}
```

But it doesn't work. However, if I specifically chose "set style sheet" on the widget the designer in QT creator, and just put

```
color: white;
```

it works.

It seems to me as if the plot isn't inhereting the top level style sheet, or for some reason my naming/syntax is wrong for selecting the plot (though the few references I've found to styling a QwtPlot online do use the same selector as me).

Can anyone help?